# Is it possible to change or override operation name of incoming request to Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way (policy or otherwise) to change or override the operation name of incoming request to Azure API management.
Currently request send by one of our API client is failing because client send 'delete' request instead of 'DELETE'. 
While creating an API, APIM gives me an option to select operation name from the list of operations (POST, PUT, DELETE) which are upper case words and it does not understand lower case 'delete', which is what client is sending.

Answer (score 0):

<s>APIM allows you to type in custom HTTP methods, and since they're case sensitive, there should be no problem defining two operations, one with DELETE method, and one with Delete.</s>

UI at the moment does not allow you to specify "Delete" as method. But you can use API to do just that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apioperation/createorupdate And APIM runtime will treat is properly.